# How can i bypass the firewal/ids/ips to get port 50000 tcp version?

Tags: security, nmap, cybersource, cyberduck

Im a cyber student and im doing CTF.
Im working on my nmap skills and i got to a question that requiers me to find the version of tcpwrapped port that is secured by firewall/ids/ips.
i tried using -sV and it didnt helped me.

Answer (score 0):

you should change for nc and change the source port. Some ports bypass by firewall

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).